# onSaveInstanceState problem while making oAuth request

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, state

Here is my scenario:

1) in my activity, user pushes Authorize button.

2) app opens WebView, in which Twitter page is loaded and user is asked to enter login and password and press Allow button. (oAuth implementation, Twitter requires it in order to integrate your app with Twitter)

3) Remote server passes Intent with Token and Secret back to my Activity, and my Activity then gets control back.

**My Problem:**

When starting this activity, through Intent, RowID variable is passed. This value I save in onSavedInstanceState when activity is pausing or when screen orientation is changed. In step 3, when my activity receives control back I loose this RowID variable. I can see why, basically activity is doing onResume and receiving intent from Twitter where there is no mention of RowID. **So, how can I save my RowID value and retrieve it when activity is resumed?** I could save it to Preferences, but is that right thing to do?

Any suggestions,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferences is the correct way to save state for such cases. simple, easy quick.

Comment: Thanks. Then I have another questions bugging me for a while. Why couldn't I always use SharedPreferences to save my activity state? Instead of using onSaveInstanceState. If I have one or two variables to save, to me it seems simplier to use SharedPreferences (not that much).

Comment: whatever is simpler is often the correct answer. I've always used preferences, never used onSaveInstanceState. Both probably work fine, but Preferences have worked fine for me, so i've never need to do anything else.